# Can I ask a practical question like this "how am I supposed to know something"

Tags: politeness, meaning

Lets say I am working on a project with 2 other people and there is some information that I need to work, so Can I ask like this:

> Can you please tell me "How am I supposed to run this script?".

instead of

> Can you please tell me "How do I run this script?".

What I am trying to ask is whether replacing **do** with **supposed to** makes the question rude?
Because usually it is used in a expression like this:

> How am I supposed to know you don't like something

Comment: If you are worried about being polite, you should change *Can* to *Could*.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for your suggestion but can I you please explain?

Comment: Because it is always more polite to use forms like *could/would* instead of *can/will* when making polite requests like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why OP is asking, since he seems to know the answer anyway.

You don't normally ask *How am I supposed to do X?* in a genuine spirit of enquiry, because it's pretty much the direct equivalent of *How do you expect me to do X?*. These forms are invariably used in hostile/beligerent/uncooperative contexts.

OP's *How do/can I do X?* is the "standard" form, but if you want to be a bit more deferential/polite, you can always ask *How **should** I do X?*

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the circumstances, on your relationship with the other party and on the tone of voice in which you ask your question. *Supposed to* **can** be said so as not to give offence, but if you are in any doubt about when and how to say it, it might be safer to avoid it. I don’t think anyone would object if you put your question as ‘Look, I’m not too sure about how I should run this script. Do you think you could give me some ideas?’